# Trying to get property 'category' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to get the name of the category to show in a table but I get the error:
 "Trying to get property 'category' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\retro\resources\views\admin\games\index.blade.php)! instead

Here is the table for the code:

```
@foreach($games as $game)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $game->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ $game->image }}</td>
        <td>£{{ $game->price }}</td>
        <td>{{ $game->category_id->category }}</td>
        <td>{{ $game->sold }}</td>
        <td>{{ $game->promote }}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The `Categories` Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categories extends Model
{
    public function games()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Games');
    }
}
```

The `Games` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Games extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Categories');
    }
}
```

And here's the migration I'm using

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('games', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->integer('category_id')->index();
        $table->integer('sold');
        $table->integer('promote');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I'm quite sure it's a relationship error but I can't see what that is.

Comment: What have you tried to debug that error? Have you checked what `$game->category_id` contains, maybe an integer (just as you defined it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$game->category_id` won't return a relationship, as you've called it `public function category()`. You need to use

```
<td>{{ $game->category->name }}</td>
```

(Not sure what column of `category` you're trying to display, guessed on `name`)

Also, follow Laravel conventions. Models names are singular, so it should be

```
class Game extends Model { ... }

class Category extends Model { ... }
```

Furthermore, you may need to provide the foreign key if the relationship doesn't quite work:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Categories', 'category_id');
```

I see another issue. You can't have `hasMany` paired with `hasOne`; there needs to be a `belongsTo` somewhere in there. A `Game` belongs to a `Category`, while a `Category` can have many `Game`s:

`Games.php`

```
class Games extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: The relationship (hasOne) is wrong. Not the foreign key.

Comment: Yeah it's better now :)

Answer (score 3):

You should change this:

```
<td>{{$game->category_id->category}}</td>
```

into this:

```
<td>{{$game->category->id}}</td>

// or if you have name property in the category table

<td>{{$game->category->name}}</td>
```

Because in your `Game` model there is a `category` function that will return the relationship object for it, based on the `category_id` that is stored in the table.

In your `Game` model, you can probably use this relationship instead:

```
public function category()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories', 'category_id');
}
```

Comment: When I try that, I get error
```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.games_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`games_id` = 1 and `categories`.`games_id` is not null limit 1) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\retro\resources\views\admin\games\index.blade.php)
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? And please check my edit as well.

Comment: The error that you've shown seems like it is coming from another place in your view.